# Android custom dialog force close issue

Tags: android, dialog, customdialog

I'm trying to implement a custom dialog which contains a ListView. The objective is to display the dialog on a button click. For this, I'm creating a custom layout for my dialog and setting the content view on button click. For some unknown reason, the app is getting force closed. Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong? Here are the code snippets:
Main Activity:

```
package com.example.zdialog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final String[] myList={"book", "table", "car", "bag", "fridge",
                "television", "radio"};
        Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
        lv.setAdapter(aa);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Dialog dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
                dialog.show();

            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="Show Dialog" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

dialog_layout.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see, the custom dialog contains a simple ListView. I know, there are other methods for implementing list based dialogs, but I just want to know what's wrong with this code (learning Android programming on my own). Please help!

Comment: post your logcat along with line number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ListView is not inside `R.layout.activity_main` so it gives you `null`

You need change these line

```
    ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
    lv.setAdapter(aa);
```

here it gives you `NullPointerException`..

so you can change it like inside your `onClick()` method..

```
    Dialog dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
    ListView lv=(ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
    lv.setAdapter(aa);
    dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

ListView is inside Dialog Layout but you are trying to get it from Activity layout so change your code as to work:

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Dialog dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
             // initialize ListView here

            ListView lv=(ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>
             (MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
            lv.setAdapter(aa);

            dialog.show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

As I can see from your above code, your `ListView` resides inside your `dialog_layout.xml` which you are setting as custom dialog background.But you are accessing it wrongly,

change your button click to following,

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Dialog dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
                ListView lv=(ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
                lv.setAdapter(aa);
                dialog.show();

            }
        });
```

And delete the `ListView` initialization that you have done earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You can not set the data into the `ListView` first and then open the dialog. Set the data into `ListView` before showing the `Dialog` and access the `Listview` with respect to the instance of the `Dialog` only.

Try out as below:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Dialog dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
           ListView lv=(ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
            lv.setAdapter(aa);
            dialog.show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to change because your ListView

```
  ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

is in your dialog_layout.xml: so change it

```
  Dialog dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
  ListView lv=(ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
  lv.setAdapter(aa);
  dialog.show();
```